# How can I make a LEFT JOIN, but with rows separed from its relations in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need to get all rows that are in the table **A**, but joining with the table **B** (basically a `LEFT JOIN`), but also, I need to get the **A** table row itself, for example, with these tables:

**Table A:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Random name |
| 2 | Random name #2 |

**Table B:**

| id | parent_id | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Location #1 |
| 2 | 2 | Location #2 |

With this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.parent_id;
```

I get something like this:

| id | name | id | parent_id | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Random name | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Random name #2 | 1 | 2 | Location #1 |
| 2 | Random name #2 | 2 | 2 | Location #2 |

But I want to get something like this:

| id | name | id | parent_id | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Random name | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Random name #2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Random name #2 | 1 | 2 | Location #1 |
| 2 | Random name #2 | 2 | 2 | Location #2 |

As you can see, there is a row by itself of "Random name #2" separated from its joins, how can I do that?

The main idea is that there are an `ads` table (the table A), but also, there are a `subads` table (the table B) with little variations of the `ads` table, and I need to show all ads and subads in a unique query.

Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.parent_id
UNION ALL
SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM A
```

or

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM (SELECT 1 A_ONLY UNION ALL SELECT 0) A_ONLY
CROSS JOIN A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.parent_id AND NOT A_ONLY
WHERE A_ONLY OR B.parent_id
```

The latter is an approach you can use to emulate WITH ROLLUP when that isn't allowed or when you want something slightly different than that produces (here, avoiding a grand total record and avoiding a double record when there are no B rows).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best implementation, but until someone comes up with a proper solution...

```
SELECT A.id, name, B.id, parent_id, location FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.parent_id;
UNION ALL
SELECT A.id, name, NULL as id, NULL as parent_id, NULL as location FROM A
WHERE A.id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM B)
```

Simply `UNION ALL` with another query taking the values from A that had matches on B, hence no NULL values from the first query.

Answer (score 1):

You can make INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN and UNION ALL with table A content:

Both queries must return the same number of columns.

```
SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL 
FROM A

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.parent_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need only the NULL added rows from A and the rest of the inner JOIN

> ```
> CREATE TABLE A
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(14))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO A
>     (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Random name'),
>     (2, 'Random name #2')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE B
>     (`id` int, `parent_id` int, `location` varchar(11))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO B
>     (`id`, `parent_id`, `location`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 2, 'Location #1'),
>     (2, 2, 'Location #2')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> (SELECT A.id as a_id,A.name,B.* FROM A
> INNER JOIN B
> ON A.id = B.parent_id)
> UNION
> (SELECT A.*,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM A)
> ORDER by a_id,id;
> ```
>
> ```
> a_id | name           |   id | parent_id | location   
> ---: | :------------- | ---: | --------: | :----------
>    1 | Random name    | null |      null | null       
>    2 | Random name #2 | null |      null | null       
>    2 | Random name #2 |    1 |         2 | Location #1
>    2 | Random name #2 |    2 |         2 | Location #2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe792f5ed70273f5ac68420e82854e39)*